# Lisp, add new list to db in "for" loop, why returning NIL?

Tags: list, loops, for-loop, lisp, null

I wonder, how can I print in LISP each new value from loop "for" in new list, which each time creates by calling the function.

I have created the func:

```
(defun make (id name surname) (list :id id :name name :surname surname) )
```

Here I created the global variable:

```
(defvar *db* nil)
```

And here I defined the func for adding each new value to store it in db:

```
(defun add (cd) (push cd *db*))
```

So, I'm able to add each new data to db, like that:

```
(add (make 0 "Oleg" "Orlov" ) )
```

To look the content of my db , I can use:

```
*db*
```

So, I wonder how to put each new record-list to db using "for" loop, I print values in "for" loop in lisp like this:

```
 (loop for i from 1 to 10 do ( ... ))
```

If , I use:

```
 (loop for i from 0 to 10 do (add (make i "Oleg" "Orlov") ) )
```

If you read db using `*db*` you will see, that all evelen records were added, but after calling the last line, you will get NIL result in return.

Why do I catch NIL result, not T and what does it mean?

Thanks, best regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every form in Lisp evaluates to something.

If a form you type in doesn't return a value, it will evaluate to `NIL` by default (otherwise, it evaluates to the value(s) it returns). Your loop doesn't actually return a value itself; it just performs 10 assignments (each of the intermediate expressions do return a value, but you don't collect and return them). Therefore, that code will return `NIL`.

If you haven't done so already, check out [chapter 3 of Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-a-simple-database.html), in which Peter Seibel goes step-by-step through creating a simple database. It might give you some insights into the basics of how Lisp works. The specific question you ask (why forms return `NIL` by default, and what it means specifically in the context of Common Lisp) is answered in [chapter 2 of the same book](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/lather-rinse-repeat-a-tour-of-the-repl.html)

As for how you would explicitly cause your `loop` to emit the list of items it added to `*db*`, try the following

```
(loop for i from 1 to 10
      for elem = (make i "Oleg" "Orlov")
      do (add elem)
      collect elem)
```